# Can't figure out do-while and do-until loops

Tags: vba, excel, do-while

I'm having trouble with the same task that I have to do in four different ways (the four do loops, basically), and it is to generate random numbers and sort them to even and odd. I have specific instructions that this has to be done using do while and do until loops, and so far I've managed to do only one of the four. 
The first problem is in the fact that the loop here won't run because nch = ch already and it checks the condition first. Is there a way to get around this? The exit conditions are no more than 290 iterations or nch = ch.

```
Cells.Clear
Randomize
ch = 0
nch = 0

Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = "Do..Until Loop"
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 2) = "Even"
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 3) = "Odd"

Do Until (nch + ch) = 290 Or nch = ch
    n = Fix((31 - 13 + 1) * Rnd) + 13
    If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
                ch = ch + 1
                Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1 + ch, 2) = n
            Else
            nch = nch + 1
            Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1 + nch, 3) = n
    End If
Loop
```

The second problem is with a do while loop, where I have to achieve the same goal, but the first condition keeps being ignored for some reason.

```
Do

   If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
                ch = ch + 1
                Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1 + ch, 2) = n
            Else
            nch = nch + 1
            Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1 + nch, 3) = n
    End If
Loop While (nch + ch) < 290 Or nch <> ch
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The `Loop While` should be `Loop While (nch + ch) < 290 And nch <> ch` (i.e. only continue while both conditions are `True`).  But I have no idea what you are expected to do with the first one - as you say, at the start there are exactly the same number of odds as evens, i.e. zero of each, so if you are meant to stop once you have the same number then you shouldn't go through the loop at all.  (Which is what your code is doing - and perhaps the teacher is expecting that to be the case.)

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I would've done this another way, but the teacher told us specifically that the exit conditions should be written out as while and until with logical operators. I'm questioning the possibility of actually doing that with the loop until. The loop while works! Thank you!

Comment: The condition with comparison of `ch` and `nch` is odd, what exactly did your teacher ask for? Do you need to stop as soon as the two values are equals, and test no more than 290 values? maybe he wants you to use a `Do... Loop Until` structure.

Comment: `Do ... Loop Until` and `Do ... Loop While` structure are executed at least one time, `Do While ... Loop` and `Do Until ... Loop` can be not executed if the exit condition is valid at the start of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have to write it as 'Loop While' for your home work.

but you could change your syntax to.

```
Do While (nch + ch) < 290
    n = Fix((31 - 13 + 1) * Rnd) + 13
    If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
        ch = ch + 1
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1 + ch, 2) = n
    Else
        nch = nch + 1
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1 + nch, 3) = n
    End If
Loop
```

And your I'm not sure your 'Do Until' needs the second check, try this:

```
Cells.Clear
Randomize
ch = 0
nch = 0

Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = "Do..Until Loop"
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 2) = "Even"
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 3) = "Odd"

Cells.Clear
Randomize
ch = 0
nch = 0

Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = "Do..Until Loop"
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 2) = "Even"
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 3) = "Odd"

Do Until (nch + ch) = 290
    n = Fix((31 - 13 + 1) * Rnd) + 13
    If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
                ch = ch + 1
                Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1 + ch, 2) = n
            Else
            nch = nch + 1
            Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1 + nch, 3) = n
    End If
Loop
```

Also its not the cleanest way but to check a criteria later on you can use this to exit the loop.

```
If ch = nch Then
    Exit Do
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a boolean to evaluate it

```
Cells.Clear
Randomize
ch = 0
nch = 0
equal = false

Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = "Do..Until Loop"
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 2) = "Even"
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 3) = "Odd"

Do Until (nch + ch) = 290 Or equal
    n = Fix((31 - 13 + 1) * Rnd) + 13
    If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
         ch = ch + 1
         Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1 + ch, 2) = n
    Else
         nch = nch + 1
         Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1 + nch, 3) = n
    End If
    If nch = ch Then
         equal = true
    End If
Loop
```

With the second example where is n defined? if n=0 the n Mod 2 will equal 0

Answer (score 0):

"until" stops if true, "while" stops when false.

```
not ( (nch + ch) = 290 Or nch = ch )
```

is

```
(nch + ch) <> 290 AND nch <> ch
```

the "or" is likely to be your problem.

Please keep in mind the two codes are not totally equivalent, as in the second, the loop is executed at least once.

Comment: Appreciate the help!